# Always returning incorrect simple math lua

Tags: math, lua, random-seed

I have a very basic Lua script that asks a math question

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
        print ("Let's play Math")
        a = math.random(1,10)
        b = math.random(1,10)
        io.write("What is " .. a .. " + " .. b .. "?")
        answer = io.read()
        correct = (a + b)
            if (answer == correct) then
                print ("Correct")
            else
                print ("Wrong")
                print (correct) --For debug
            end
```

For some reason, I am always getting "incorrect" even when answered correctly. I also print out the correct answer, just to make sure the program is handling the math correctly. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`answer` contains a string and so is never equal to a number.

Just add

```
    answer = tonumber(answer)
```

after

```
    answer = io.read()
```

Comment: It works, and thanks for the explanation, that's very helpful.