# Lua 2nd nested if statement is ignored

Tags: if-statement, lua

I am writing a tic tac toe game for my assignment, and I was stuck with the nested if statement. Attached part of my code below:

```
if name[1] == "AI" then 
     print("test string")
     playerId = 1
     if level == 1 or level == 2 then
        print("AI lvl 1/2")
        easy()
     elseif level == 3 then
        print("AI lvl 3")
        hard()
     end
elseif name[1] == "player" then
    print("test string2")
    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", fill)
end
```

while this executed, test string was printed on console, and playerId = 1, but inside 2nd if statement was completely ignored. Not even print on console.
Could someone help me solve it please? Or tell me what is wrong with my code.
Thanks

Comment: test string2 was printed while name[1] == "player"

Comment: Check what the value of `level` is. It sounds like it's something other than 1, 2 or 3. Where are you getting it from? If you post the code where `level` is defined we might be able to give you some more specific help.

Comment: in this scene: local level = composer.getVariable("level"), in the difficulty level scene, composer.setVariable( "level", "1" ), level represents difficulty level, only 1,2,3

Comment: after adding    print("level"..level)    below playerId =1 of above codes, it prints level 1/2/3 while I selected related level.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532017/always-returning-incorrect-simple-math-lua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something like `print(level, type(level))` to see what `level` is. Remember, lua can convert strings like `'123'` to numbers and vice versa when you want to do some arithmetics or string concatenations, but you can't compare strings with numbers like that: `123 == '123'` will return `false`.

So, if `level` is a string, either replace `1`, `2` and `3` in your code with `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'`, or convert `level` to a number: `level = tonumber(level)`